# How to use cron-parser module in angular2 application

Tags: angular

I am a relatively newbie for angular2 development.

In my angular2 application, I am expecting the user to enter crontab entries in a textfield, which I want to validate.

For this purpose, I want to use [cron-parser module from node js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-parser) in my application.

I tried to use 'require' and 'import' statatements........however with no success.

Please point me to any information on how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean with no success ? stack traces would be helpful , what did you do ?

Comment: 1. I tried var parser = require('cron-parser'); ... as given in the module docs.

Comment: and the error ? could you post it .. it would be helpful

Comment: 1. I tried var parser = require('cron-parser'); ... as given in the module docs.This gave me errors as the file not found.......Then I tried to edit systemjs.config.js to include data in map and packages........It found the js file after that............But errored out saying ghat 'fs' module not found..........I tried to comment out that part in the module code.....It then said 'is-nan' not found.............Basically I do not know any standard way to use such node.js modules. I am just trying by hitting and missing.....That is the reason I asked this question here. I hope I am clear. Thanks.

Comment: well i'd no experience in it , I thought you were blocked at some stage and you are knowing what are you doing , since you are hitting and missing , Hope there'll be someone here with an already passed experience with cron-parser to give a hand.

Answer (score 4):

If using the angular-cli...

```
npm install cron-parser --save
```

Then in your angular component:

```
import * as parser from 'cron-parser';
```